# Reset all categories store view use default value

Tags: magento-1.9, category, database, ce-1.9.2.2

how can I reset all my store views value to use default "All Store View" value?

Which database table(s) should be done that?

I have 279 categories and 2 store views.

Magento v1.9.2.2

Answer (score 1):

Simple steps to solve it:

1. Make a backup of your database if something goes wrong.
2. Find a store view id for which you want to remove a table.
3. Execute query for every backend type of attribute in category:

   - `DELETE FROM catalog_category_entity_int where store_id = 'store_id_to_remove value from'`
   - `DELETE FROM catalog_category_entity_varchar where store_id = 'store_id_to_remove value from'`
   - `DELETE FROM catalog_category_entity_text where store_id = 'store_id_to_remove value from'`
   - `DELETE FROM catalog_category_entity_decimal where store_id = 'store_id_to_remove value from'`
   - `DELETE FROM catalog_category_entity_datetime where store_id = 'store_id_to_remove value from'`
4. Check everything is correct, otherwise restore from dump and check what went wrong.